# jquery id from list items?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, list

Ok, so i've got a list of usernames from the mysql database. But, i need the ID from the database so i was thinking something like this,

```
<li id='43'>Monica</li>
<li id='47'>Henrik</li>
<li id='77'>Eric</li>
```

But how can i get the ID from the list?

Comment: Is your question "how to get the id for the `li` elements *from* the database?" or "how go get the id *of* the `li` elements?"

Comment: [ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter (A-Za-z) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits (0-9), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#h-6.2)

Comment: Do not start an id with number. Here are rules for choosing ids: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html/79022#79022

Comment: @epascarello and @Ivan, **unless** it's under a html5 doctype. It's only html4 (and presumably below) that refuse to accept numbers as the first characters of an `id`. References: [HTML5 allows almost any value for the `id` attribute, use wisely](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201011/html5_allows_almost_any_value_for_the_id_attribute_use_wisely/).

Comment: ... and that will be safe to use about 2018. But thanks for info.

Comment: @Ivan actually it's safe to use now, since the spec is based on existing browser behaviour.

Comment: Yeah you are right, I was wrong :)

Answer (score 6):

I would use something like the following:

```
<ul id="items-list">
    <li id='member-43'>Monica</li>
    <li id='member-47'>Henrik</li>
    <li id='member-77'>Eric</li>
</ul>
```

then:

```
$('#items-list li').each(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[1];
});
```

It was pointed out in the comments that [as of HTML5](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201011/html5_allows_almost_any_value_for_the_id_attribute_use_wisely/) it's perfectly valid to start an `id` attribute with a number, but I'd still give preference to this method, especially if there are to be multiple lists on a page from different DB tables (`id`s still need to be unique). An `id` of `43` has no meaning to anyone, but `member-43` is much more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Have a normal javascript on click event for the list element as shown below:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      linkClicked = function (index) {
        alert($('#myList li').get(index).id);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id='myList'>
      <li id='43' onclick="linkClicked($(this).index())">Monica</li>
      <li id='47' onclick="linkClicked($(this).index())">Henrik</li>
      <li id='77' onclick="linkClicked($(this).index())">Eric</li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

This worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

You could add a class with the same name to all of the list items

```
<li class="test" id='43'>Monica</li>
<li class="test" id='47'>Henrik</li>
<li class="test" id='77'>Eric</li>
```

Then you could use an on

```
$(".test").click(function(){
$(this).attr("id");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li').each(function(){
  alert( $(this).attr('id') );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("li").eq(0).attr("id")
```

Substitute 0 by the index item of the list item you want to read the id of.

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually want to do something with that id? There is too little data that you gave us.
If you want to administer users you would need something like this:

```
<ul id="deleteUsers">
  <li id='user43'><a href="deleteuser.php?id=43">Monica</a></li>
  <li id='user47'><a href="deleteuser.php?id=47">Henrik</a></li>
  <li id='user77'><a href="deleteuser.php?id=77">Eric</a></li>
</ul>
```

And than in jQuery override click event. roryf gave you good example.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use HTML5 Data Attribute in order to hold ID Data . Holding data in ID may give problem if you require to define id statically at some place so not an optimal solution  You can check code below -

```
<li  data-empid="A123" data-salary="120" class="datalist">Monica</li>
<li data-empid="A124" data-salary="121" class="datalist">Monica</li>
```

**Access Data in Data Attribute in Jquery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $( "li .datalist" ).click(function() {    
       $(this).data("salary")
    });
</script>
```